# Resize based on dropdown items in azure-devops-ui

Tags: typescript, azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

I'm trying to develop an extension for the work item form in Azure DevOps with the editable dropdown (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-devops/components/editable-dropdown#freeform-editable-dropdown) but the dropdown window in the iFrame is too small and needs to be resized when expanding the dropdown. Right now, when the dropdown is expanded, it will expand the iFrame but then when the dropdown is collapsed, it will keep the same size when it should shrink again.

I've tried using the azure-devops-extension-sdk with the `Resize()` method + `onExpand/onCollapse` properties in azure-devops-ui but it doesn't work correctly (flashes then closes, tried with caching but still doesn't work as expected). The work item form should expand the dropdown window when expanded and collapse the space between the fields when the dropdown is collapsed. This issue seems to only show in the work item form.

Is there some built-in method in the azure-devops-ui or similar that can handle expanding the iFrame and collapsing when the dropdown is expanded and collapsed? I'm not sure if renderExpandable is what I'm looking for or something else.

```
import * as React from "react";
import { EditableDropdown } from "azure-devops-ui/EditableDropdown";
import { editableDropdownItems } from "./Data";

export default class DropdownMultiSelectExample extends React.Component {

    public render() {
        return (
            <div className="flex-row" style={{ margin: "8px", alignItems: "center" }}>
                <EditableDropdown
                    items={editableDropdownItems}
                    renderExpandable={this.context.items}
                />           
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: did you find the solution? if so could you post it here, bsc I am also stuck to arrange the size of Dropdown component

Comment: Unfortunately didn't :(

Comment: I set the `width` attribute which effects expanded window of Dropdown. It does not look professional but at least the user could read the items